# Magento Mage::getModel('core/email_template') returns an empty object

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem with my Magento 1.9.0.1 site where Mage::getModel('core/email_template') returns an empty object, meaning pretty-much everything fails to work (such as creating orders, where the order gets sent to the customer, adding comments etc...).

For example, I'm regularly seeing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addBcc() on a non-object in /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php on line 69
```

Doing some detective work, I found that:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

returns false, therefore giving the above error.

Could it be a plugin causing an issue? Does `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')` somehow load a model from elsewhere, rather than the expected `/home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you include the stacktrace of the fatal error? we need to find out where it comes from, what module triggers it

Comment: Could you confirm that you installed this two plugins, please? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/moogento-pickpack-custom-pdfs-pick-lists-packing-sheets-invoices-csvs-works-with-all-order-statuses.html  and http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/custom-smtp.html

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::getModel('core/email_template')` should not return false, so it is probably overriden by some other module indeed.
To find out which module is responsible, look for this snippet in the `config.xml` files:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <email_template>Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
</global>
```

note that `Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template` will be different, `Namespace` will be the namespace of the module, `Module` will be the module's name and what comes after `Model` can be totally different. Also, there may be some other tags between the one I put in the snippet.
Easiest way to find it, is to look for the string `<email_template>` in the `config.xml` files.

Once you find out which module is responsible, you/we will have to look into the class that is overriding the core one to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So far, I can see six files with "<email_template>": ./app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/etc/config.xml, ./app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml, ./app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml, ./app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml, ./app/code/local/AW/Customsmtp/etc/config.xml, ./app/code/local/Moogento/Pickpack/etc/config.xml

Comment: My guess would be the AW_Customsmtp module. Do you really need it? Anyway, try disable it to check if this is the guilty. (change `true` by `false` in app/etc/modules/AW_Customsmtp.xml)

Comment: Boo :( I disabled both AW_Customsmtp and Moogento_Pickpack and the error is still there. What's stranger is that I have another site utilising pretty-much the exact same setup and it works. When I add a comment to an order (which invokes the email sending) on the working site, I dumped the `$emailTemplate` variable which turned out to be a class derived from the Moogento plugin. Both sites use this, but the one site isn't working regardless of whether it's enabled or not. The hunt goes on...

Comment: did you flush the cache between disabling them and testing?

Comment: Yes I did (sorry I should have said!).

Comment: I suggest reverting the change: enable both AW_Customsmtp and Moogento_Pickpack and let's go on with the bug search.

Comment: They're enabled, and I'm fairly certain it's to do with the PickPack module by Moogento, but it works on a "sister" site no problems... Thanks for all your help and comments so far... the hunt goes on :(

Comment: @a1phanumeric please include stack trace in your question

Comment: @a1phanumeric: Is this the module you are talking about?  http://www.moogento.com/magento-pickpack-picklist

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same error with something I was working on. The issue (for me) was that that my `Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template` file was there, but the class wasn't declared with the same name (It was something along the lines of `AnotherNamespace_Module_Model_Email_Template`). It's strange that it doesn't work for you even though you disabled the modules, but maybe open them up and make sure that the declared class name matches whatever is in the `<email_template>` section.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug your problem in this way step by step:

- Use version control (for example, Git) when making changes to code so
  that, in case you need it, you can undo changes easily.
- Clear the Magento cache deleteting everything inside /var/cache/
- Clear your browser cache.
- Turn on logging: Using Admin panel, go to
  System>Configuration>Developer>Log Settings and choose “Yes” on
  Enabled option. Two files are going to be created inside var/log
  folder (Note: I think you have already turned on logging but I am not
  sure you did...just mentioning this just in case you have not).
- Install a PHP IDE, then install Xdebug debugger and confirm that
  $emailTemplate is false. Take into account that we are talking about 
  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php (line 69)
  which calls addBcc() which is defined at
  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php (line 538).
- Disable modules: Read https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/13421
  where it says “Disable local modules”. I would disable AW_Customsmtp 
  first and check if error appears. If not, enable it, disable
  Moogento_Pickpack and check again. If error does not appear, disable 
  both and check again.